# use of wait and notify methods to print a sequence

Tags: multithreading, wait, notify

I have two threads t1,t2. t1 has odd numbers and t2 has even numbers array in it. using wait and notify methods I want to print the sequence. for example t1 has array of 1,3,5,7,9 and t2 has array of 2,4,6,8,10. by using threading concept I want to print 1,2,3,4,5.......10. that too using wait and notify methods. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I see it something like this.

#### Start

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

#### In t1

```
t1.print();
t1.notify();
t1.wait();
```

#### In t2

```
t2.print();
t2.notify();
t2.wait();
```

Basically threads are grouped in a thread-group. When you call notify on a thread, it wakes up all threads in the thread-group. Than you call wait to put this thread to sleep until it is notified by another.

Comment: You didn't ask for the algorithm in a specific language. If you give us what you tried to program yourself than we could help you. Otherwise we can't.

Comment: Actually \i was given an assignment to print the sequence using wait and notify methods. i have used sleep method to print the sequence. but the seq is unpredictable . can anyone help me

Comment: What language are you using ?